# What's a good way to rotate IP addresses when building a web scraper?

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, web-crawler

I'm trying to get an understanding of how to build programs that commonly encounter IP-based blocking/throttling etc. (like crawlers/scrapers).

Would love to find out some popular solutions for this (I'm flexible on the language: java, python, javascript - anything)

Let's take an example.

```
function scrape(index){
    website = request(websites[index]);
    doStuffWithScrapedData(website);
}

function init(){
  for (i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
    scrape(i);
  }
}
```

Let's say I'm scraping a website and I have a bunch of URLs (different paths to same website) and I just want to GET them one by one. To avoid running into IP related blocks, I would like to do something like:

```
function init(){
  for (i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
    scrape(i);
    if(i % 100 == 0) rotateIpAddress();
  }
}
```

That is, after 100 requests, somehow change the website facing IP address, i.e proxy the request through an intermediary to get around blocking.

I'm interested in how `rotateIpAddress()` can be implemented. (Language-agnostic, I'm okay with just learning the tools of the trade, common terms etc.)

Comment: Keep proxies in an array, shift() one off the front, set it, and then push() it to the end.

Comment: Could you expand on that? What does that mean? How do I actually use a proxy assuming I have an array of proxy IP addresses? How do I tell my program "Use this as a proxy for next request"?

Comment: It depends on what you're using. type the name of the library you're using and proxy into google and you should find an answer.